# React Hooks will render multiple times after await

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const [ html, setHTML ] = useState('');
const [ script, setScript ] = useState('');

const update = (script, html) => {
  setScript(script);
  setHTML(html);
};

update('a', 'b'); // actual code in an event handler
```

The above code works fine, React Hooks will render ONCE and combine setScript & setHTML;

```
const [ html, setHTML ] = useState('');
const [ script, setScript ] = useState('');

const update = async (script, html) => {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10));
  setScript(script);
  setHTML(html);
};

update('a', 'b'); // actual code in an event handler
```

The above code doesn't work anymore, React Hooks will render TWICE and it doesn't combine setScript & setHTML.

I can change to the code to:

```
const [ state, setState ] = useState({
  html: '',
  script: ''
});

const update = async (script, html) => {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10));
  setState({
    script,
    html
  });
};

update('a', 'b'); // actual code in an event handler
```

The above code only renders ONCE but it has a new bug: the cursor in the textArea (where script and html go) will move to the end of the textArea instead of staying at where it is.

Answer (score 0):

This is inevitable: when you run your code asynchronously, React has no way of knowing that more synchronous setters could be executed after the current one, so it has to trigger render for each. You can either batch by making a single state object, like you did, or use `unstable_batchedUpdates`:

```
import {unstable_batchedUpdates as batchedUpdates} from 'react-dom';

// ....

const [ html, setHTML ] = useState('');
const [ script, setScript ] = useState('');

const update = async (script, html) => {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10));
    batchedUpdates(() => {
        setScript(script);
        setHTML(html);
    });
};

update('a', 'b');
```